# DOCKER manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to pull the images I created and I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d
Pulling hub (dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-hub:3.0.0)...
Trying to pull repository dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-hub ...
ERROR: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
We are Spinning up 2 Browsers.
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose scale chrome=2 firefox=2
Creating and starting execution_chrome_1 ...
Creating and starting execution_chrome_2 ...
Pulling chrome (dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-chrome-node:53.0.3)...
Pulling chrome (dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-chrome-node:53.0.3)...
Trying to pull repository dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-chrome-node ... 
Trying to pull repository dockyard.cloud.capitalone.com/entepriseatdd/selenium-chrome-node ...

ERROR: for execution_chrome_1  manifest unknown: manifest unknown

ERROR: for execution_chrome_2  manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Comment: resolved this , by creating a new image with the updated docker version

Answer (score 78):

It usually occurs when the image does not exist on the local machine or in the registry you are looking for.

Suppose I have an image called **repository-name/image-name:v1.0.0**

For the following docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
    # an example of docker compose
    version: '2'
    services:
      my-service-name:
        image: repository-name/image-name:v1.0.0
        restart: always
```

I get the same error when trying to use a docker image stored on the [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) in two situations:

When I type the wrong name of the image.

```yaml
    # a wrong example
    version: '2'
    services:
      my-service-name:
        image: repository-name/image-wrong-name:v1.0.0
        restart: always
```

The command "docker-compose up", returns the error:

```sh
    /usr/bin/docker-compose up -d

    Pulling my-service-name (repository-name/image-wrong-name:v1.0.0)...
    ERROR: manifest for repository-name/image-wrong-name:v1.0.0 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Or if the version of the image doesn't exist.

```yaml
    # a wrong example
    version: '2'
    services:
      my-service-name:
        image: repository-name/image-name:v1.0.1
        restart: always
```

I have the same error:

```sh
    /usr/bin/docker-compose up -d

    Pulling my-service-name (repository-name/image-name:v1.0.1)...
    ERROR: manifest for repository-name/image-name:v1.0.1 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Information about my environment:

- The operating system platform is Linux (Ubuntu 16.04);
- The output of the docker version command

```sh
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
     Version:           19.03.12
     API version:       1.40
     Go version:        go1.13.10
     Git commit:        48a66213fe
     Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:45:49 2020
     OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
     Experimental:      false
    
    Server: Docker Engine - Community
     Engine:
      Version:          19.03.12
      API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
      Go version:       go1.13.10
      Git commit:       48a66213fe
      Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:44:20 2020
      OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
      Experimental:     false
     containerd:
      Version:          1.2.13
      GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
     runc:
      Version:          1.0.0-rc10
      GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
     docker-init:
      Version:          0.18.0
      GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: Hitting this question repeatedly. Forgotten tag (`docker pull repo/image` where only `repo/image:other_than_latest_tag` exists) is most silly bug in my case.

Answer (score 42):

I got the same error recently. It happens because you need to specify the tag.

ie: `docker pull envoyproxy/envoy:v1.18.3`

If you try to do:

```
docker pull envoyproxy/envoy
```

You hit the following issue:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for envoyproxy/envoy:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Btw 'latest' does not work as version.

Comment: It's called "tag" not "version".

Answer (score 3):

When you don't run the latest version of the docker image you need to mention the version starting with the ':' at the end of the image.

eg: repository-name/image-name:<version_number>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen after I deleted images from my private registry,because images I didn't delete depended on the ones I deleted. The registry was on my build server, so I had the source for the repo available in `.../jenkins_home/workspace/MYPROJECT_projname_MYTAG`. I went there and rebuilt the image with `--no-cache` so it would stop relying on deleted images, and pushed it to the registry.

```sh
IMAGE_NAME=my/image
TAG=PR-59
docker build . -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}temp --no-cache
docker tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}temp $REGISTRY_IP:$REGISTRY_PORT/${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}
docker push $REGISTRY_IP:$REGISTRY_PORT/${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}
```