# Can't run jenkins image in docker

Tags: jenkins

I have just started to learn Docker.
I have tried to run jenkins in my docker.

I have tried the commands:
docker run jenkins ,
docker run jenkins:latest

But showing the error in the docker interactive shell:
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: manifest for jenkins:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as described in an older post dealing with the same error message. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474733/6710366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the container by using the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) page is pretty good.

I would use a docker-compose file to

- mount a volume for home to make it persistent
  (in order to look into the build workspace you need to attach another container to it)
- control the version programmatically
- add docker client or other utilities installed later
- add 'fixed' agents

docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  jenkins-server:
    build: ./JenkinsServer
    container_name: jenkins
    restart: always
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1024m"
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      jenkins:
        aliases:
          - jenkins
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home

networks:
  jenkins:
    external: true

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
    external: true
```

dockerfile for server:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.263.2-lts
USER root
```