# docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for jenkins:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose

I want run this line:

```
docker run --name myjenkins1 -v myvoll:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins
```

But result is:

> Unable to find image 'jenkins:latest' locally
> docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for jenkins:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
> See 'docker run --help'.

How can i solve this ...

Comment: does this work for you

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as described in an older post dealing with the same error message. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474733/6710366

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The jenkins image has been deprecated for over 2 years in favor of the jenkins/jenkins:lts image provided and maintained by the Jenkins Community as part of the project's release process.
Use below image:
`docker pull jenkins/jenkins`
`docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master -d jenkins/jenkins`

For more info:
https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins

Comment: Probably they should change the docs here https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins

Answer (score 12):

```
docker pull jenkins
```

Will not work as it is deprecated.

DEPRECATED; use "jenkins/jenkins:lts" instead use

```
docker pull  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: That one works. In Docker hub says: ``` This image has been deprecated for over 2 years in favor of the jenkins/jenkins:lts image provided and maintained by the Jenkins Community as part of the project's release process. The images found here have not received updates for over 2 years and will not receive any updates in the future.

Remaining tags are here only for historical reasons, none of them are supported and none of them should be used.```

Answer (score 9):

## Use : docker run -p 8080:8080 `jenkins/jenkins`

Use

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins
```

Not

```
docker pull jenkins
```

Jenkins will give an error response if you are trying to use the latest tag.

so you can execute your command as the following :

```
docker run --name myjenkins1 -v myvoll:/var/jenkins_home -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins
```

Answer (score 6):

Type `docker search jenkins` in the terminal

#### result

```
(base) kimseongjung@song-ui-MacBookPro ~ % docker search jenkins
NAME                               DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
jenkins                            DEPRECATED; ***use "jenkins/jenkins:lts" <-※ here!!!!!!!  instead   5548      [OK]       
jenkins/jenkins                    The leading open source automation server       3223                 
jenkins/jnlp-slave                 a Jenkins agent which can connect to Jenkins…   151                  [OK]
jenkins/inbound-agent
```

The message says that `jenkins` is deprecated and that `jenkins/jenkins:lts` should be used instead.

typing the code below into the terminal will solve the problem.

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When using new m1 chip macbooks, just pulling the jenkins latest ,will give below error.
docker pull jenkins

*Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for jenkins:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown*

solution : docker pull jenkins/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You might be running a deprecated code. Use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

docker pull jenkins/jenkins
This works in AWS latest in 2023 without getting any error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).