# Docker-compose Error response from daemon: manifest for nginx:1.15-alphine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've the docker compose project. Below is the project structure.

```
$ tree .
├── conf
│   └── default.conf
└── docker-compose.yaml
```

Below is the `conf/default.conf` file -

```
upstream bankservers {
    server 172.17.0.1:6565
    server 172.17.0.1:7575
}
server {
    listen 8585 http2;

    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://bankservers
    }
}
```

Below is the `docker-compose.yaml` -

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alphine
    volumes:
      - .conf:/etc/nginx/conf.f
    ports:
      - 80:8585
```

When I run docker-compose up , I get the below error

> $ sudo docker-compose up
> [+] Running 0/1
> ⠿ nginx Error                                                          0.7s
> Error response from daemon: manifest for nginx:1.15-alphine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as described in an older post dealing with the same error message. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63474733/6710366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just a typo. The image should be  `nginx:1.15-alpine`

When the image is not found on docker hub, docker-compose can not parse the yml apparently and give us a very beautiful self explaining error message.

`manifest for nginx:1.15-alphine not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`