# Error response from daemon: manifest for abhishek8054/token-app:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker, deployment, devops, production

I had made my own Docker image that is a simple react app and pushed it onto the docker hub.
Now I am trying to pull my image in system then it shows me an error

> Error response from daemon: manifest for abhishek8054/token-app:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown".

I am doing something wrong.

My `Dockerfile` code is:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app/
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

And I made the image from the following command:

```
docker image build -t abhishek8054/token-app:latest .
```

And pushed my image with the following command:

```
docker push abhishek8054/token-app:latest
```

And pulled it again with the following command:

```
docker pull abhishek/8054/token-app
```

And it gives me the error above.

Comment: I have posted a command try using that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DOCKER manifest unknown: manifest unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810104/docker-manifest-unknown-manifest-unknown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below command to pull the docker image. The issue which you are facing is that u have pushed the image with the name **abhishek8054/token-app:latest** so if you need to pull the same image you will need to pull using the same image name and tag.

```
docker pull abhishek8054/token-app:latest
```

Its not mandatory to have latest tag by default if you have not mentioned any tag docker pulls the latest image from the container registry

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Can you check if the image has been pushed to the container registry ?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/abhishek8054/token-app kindly check is there anything wrong with this

Comment: Like i said there is no image in this registry so it is unable to pull that image. Was the docker push successful ?

Comment: I feel that docker push or docker build has failed in your case as i cant find any image in your registry. If the push was successful then you would be able to see the images present in the registry. It would look similar to this - https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/sidharthpai/node

Comment: The push refers to repository [docker.io/abhishek8054/token-app]
2ce3cb92ae31: Pushed
70a01edaa692: Pushed
1a5ca9ac5515: Layer already exists
58eca630b168: Layer already exists
f1ed0bba6314: Layer already exists
2808ff9120f2: Layer already exists
cb6eda6d73f0: Layer already exists
994393dc58e7: Layer already exists
1.0.0: digest: sha256:b2ec6e5501737dc6b63d79a4e490f1e3c6ce8818c02637514cf509a8f84949b2 size: 1999

Comment: Now try to pull using the command  - docker pull abhishek8054/token-app:1.0.0

Comment: yes now its working I am again push my image

Comment: If you are able to pull the image please mark this answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 6):

The error means that docker is not able to find the image version mentioned to pull from. Please try changing the version to use latest or specific version

```
docker pull repository/image_name:latest 
docker pull repository/image_name:<version>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because there seems to be no image tagged as latest at this point
you can use the Deezer/spleeter:3.8 image for now. In the near future, they'll use this as the latest